# Getting GetProjects is not a function Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using react-boilerplate and I want to call getProjects on page loading time but I am getting error getProjects is not a function while calling inside useEffect:-

```
export function Projects({getProjects}) {

  useEffect(() => {
    // Dispatch getProjects action on component mount
    getProjects()
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
         <p>Testing Projects</p>
    </div>
  );
}

Projects.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  projects: makeSelectProjects(),

});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    getProjects: () => dispatch(getProjects()),
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'projects', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'projects', saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect
)(Projects);
```

Here is my my action.js file's content:-

```
import {GET_PROJECTS } from './constants';

export function getProjects() {
  console.log("getProjects called")
  return {
    type: GET_PROJECTS
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `getProjects` function inside `mapDispatchToProps` coming from? You show the definition inside `action.js`, but are missing the `import` inside your `Projects` component file.

Comment: I am importing using this line--import { getProjects } from './actions';